# Get text of selected couple of checkboxes android?

Tags: android

I have 700 checkboxes in my activity xml. I need to get the text of all the selected checkboxes.

One approach is to see if checkbox1 `isChecked()` and get the text, but doing this for 700 checkboxes is too repetitive.

Comment: Do you have the checkboxes in a ListView/RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach could be, start with an empty String array (representing zero checkboxes selected). Every time you select a checkbox, add it's text to the array, every time you uncheck the checkbox, remove that string from the array (if it exists there). In the end, you just need to loop your array to get the selected strings

EDIT:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private lateinit var checkbox1: CheckBox
private lateinit var checkbox2: CheckBox
private lateinit var checkboxContainer: ConstraintLayout
private var checkedStrings = ArrayList<String>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    checkbox1 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox1)
    checkbox2 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox2)
    checkboxContainer = findViewById(R.id.checkboxContainer)

    checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)
    checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)

    //or, if you have the checkboxes statically added to your layout, which I suspect you do, you can loop through the view like:
    for (i in 0..checkboxContainer.childCount){
        if (checkboxContainer.getChildAt(i) is CheckBox){
            (checkboxContainer.getChildAt(i) as CheckBox).setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {

    val checkBoxString = (buttonView as CheckBox).text.toString()

    if (isChecked){
        checkedStrings.add(checkBoxString)
    }else{
        checkedStrings.remove(checkBoxString)
    }
}

fun processStrings(){

    // at the end of the iteration/screen/whatever you can check the content of the checkedStrings array like, for instance:

    for (string in checkedStrings){
        Log.e("print string", string)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comments, please if you explain with an example. thanks, chandan

Comment: @ChandanBera I edited my response with a quick Kotlin example for this. Didn't test but should work